# .NET object that is being called by Coldfusion cfobject always thows exception

Tags: .net, coldfusion

I have a C#.NET application with several Projects (Dlls) and classes.  I have a requirement for coldfusion to call a method within a .NET assembly (compiled code).  This assembly contains a method that is being called by CF.  The method takes in about 4 string variables.  The method instantiates classes from other assemblies (also part of the .Net solution) and performs several database operations.

I've ran the .NET code that is part of the project within Visual Studio by calling it early within the Page_Load() and passing in the variables that are being passed from CF and it works flawlessly.  However, when I execute it from coldfusion it Crashes with a "Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object".  I'm able to pull these values simply based on putting try,catch blocks on my code.

I've tried adding additional assemblies since the project has them.  I suspect that maybe no database calls can be made.  I also notice I can't access values within the web.config of .NET using the configuration manager.

```
'''cf
<cfset dll1 = expandPath('../../loc/loc/some.dll')>
<cfset dll2 = expandPath('../../loc/loc/some2.dll')>
<cfset dll3 = expandPath('../../loc/loc/some3.dll')>

<cfobject type=".NET" name="Doit" class="Namespace.PartialClass" assembly="#dll1#,#dll2#,#dll3#,#dll4#,#dll5#">

<cfset Doit.init()>     

<!---Doing this so I can see what's available to me--->
<cfdump var="#Doit#">

<cfset s = Doit.AMethodinNET(varstring1, varstring2, varstring3, ToString(someint))>

<cfoutput>#s#</cfoutput>
'''
```

//Below is the .net code.  It fails around the 2nd Someclass instantiation.

```
'''.NET
public string Doit(string somevar1, string somevar2, string somevar3, int somevar4)

        {           
            try

            { 

                SomeClass.Hey.Someclass classname1 = new SomeClass.Hey.Someclass();

                SomeClass.Hey.Someclassprop prop = classname1.CreateNewUserObject(getPermission(Convert.ToInt32(somevar3)), Convert.ToInt32(somevar4));


                prop.somevar1 = somevar1;
                prop.fName = "Water";
                prop.lName = "dog";
                prop.email = somevar4;
                prop.phone = somevar3;
                prop.rawPassword = somevar2;
                prop.companyId = Convert.ToInt32(somevar4);
                prop.pos = "typer";
                prop.role = "admin"; 

                SomeClass.AddUpdateUser(Convert.ToInt32(somevar3), prop);

            }


            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.ToString();
            } 

            return null;

        }
'''
```

Comment: Can you wrap it in a try catch and add a screenshot of the error? I wonder if one assembly would work better than a bunch of assemblies

Comment: I just tried <cftry> and <cfcatch> (first time using these) and I tried within the <cfcatch> a dump of #cfcatch.type# #cfcatch.message# etc..  But notting came back.  There is actually no CF error just the error coming back from the .NET code.

Comment: Oh, initially I used only one assembly.  The assembly that was being referenced by the code I'm using.  However I added all the the project assemblies later.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the logs? Take a look in the `cf_install_root\logs` directory.

Comment: I did check the logs and I'm not getting anything unusual.

Comment: Temporarily comment out the catch clause(s) in the .net code, so you can see the entire exception trace.  *fails around the 2nd Someclass instantiation.*  Try splitting up the nested calls to make it easier to determine which piece of code is erroring out. Also, what does Someclass do, i.e. Is it accessing any external resources, files, etc... ?

Comment: It appears to me that the 4th argument is integer, not string.

Comment: It is, but if CF was unable to resolve the method signature, it shouldn't make it as far as executing code inside the method.  *I'm not getting anything unusual* Specifically which files did you check? In addition to the various exception logs, there's also a `dotnet.log`.  *can't access values within the web.config of .NET using the configuration manager.* Hmm... web? Is this a class library or something that's part of a web/ui application? Because there are some limitations on what you can and can't do with .net components.

Answer (score 1):

it was decided to go another route, considering the complexity of doing "this piece of work" with .NET.   Anyway to answer the questions, if you remove the try/catch blocks then no error will come back from the .NET nor any error from the coldfusion.  As far as coldfusion is concerned no error occurred.

Regardless I spent several days and hours working on code and trying for figure out what's going on.  If there was an answer I would have had found it by that time.  Anyway, the other thing I didn't like is that once you deployed an assembly and once Coldfusion is pointed to it you can't delete or redeploy that dll until you stop the coldfusion .net service.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :-/.  There's not a huge amount of info out there about the .net stuff. A few similar questions on Adobe's forum and S.O. but no resolutions. Unfortunately no one's ever taken the time to post a complete repro case, for others to test.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!!!!  There's not a whole lot out there.  What was frusterating is that I INDIVIDUALLY tested each area of code.  So I created a generic .NET "Hello world" app that worked perfectly when called from CF.  I INDIVIDUALLY tested the CF code as well and both work.  Then I had to create the .NET code that would have been called from CF and individually tested that as well.  It all worked.  However CF didn't seem to work well with "complex" .net.  The .NET method was instantiating multiple classes from other assemblies and passing in variables and it seemed not to take well

Comment: Well that sucks... Sounds like you did everything I would do. There have to be some debug settings we CF developers aren't aware of...  If you get a chance, might be helpful if you put an example on github, minus any proprietary stuff, so someone could troubleshoot it. At the very least there'd be an example to point Adobe to, if it turns out it's a bug...